# how to prevent gmail from being the default client with mailto links?

Tags: gmail, mailto

I'm using google chrome, is there some setting somewhere I can change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to chrome://settings/handlers and remove the setting for gmail.
It is under Privacy then content settings.

Comment: thanks Chapkom, this worked but now the mailto links are dead, how to switch the handlers to Apple Mail? There is no add option in `chrome://settings/handlers`

Comment: Give this a try: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Email-Client-on-Mac-OS-X

Comment: yep that did it, this seems like a sneaky thing google is doing to redirect all your mail to gmail, i never changed any setting leading up to this issue, it just happened automatically one day, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It should respond to the windows defaults which are set in:-

> control panel > internet options > programs > set programs

This will set the mail client for all programs including chrome.

Comment: hi toomanyairmiles, i'm using Mac OS X lion, any thoughts on considering Chapkom's suggestion above? thanks!